# Laravel5 Carbon and time

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I have problem with Carbon and Laravel , I receive the format date dd/mm/yyyy correctly with the Request.

```
$birthda = Request::input("birthday");
```

Then, I have this code

```
$user = new User;
        $user->nif=$nif;
        $user->name =$name;
        $user->surname=$surname;
        $user->birthday=Carbon::parse($birthda)->format('d/m/Y');
```

In the database I have the format date , for this reason the row receive this YYYY-MM-DD , I create the user correctly but in the database I put 0000-00-00 I need to use other type of row?

Comment: Can you try to write in the end: `dd($user->birthday);` and see what happens?

Comment: Try `Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $birthda);` instead, or remove the `->format('d/m/Y')`, it should be able to figure it out by itself.

Comment: Solve , thanks @JonasLomholdt

Comment: try using Carbon::parse($birthda)->toDateString(); or Carbon::parse($birthda)->toDateTimeString(); it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $birthda);` instead, or remove the `->format('d/m/Y')`, it should be able to figure it out by itself.